# R: library(BTYD): possible to add more predictors?

Tags: r, prediction

I've been using `BTYD package` for predicting customer churn and number of orders in the future, but I find the included models (`Pareto/NBD`, `BG/NBD` and `BG/BB`) limited in the sense that they only take recency, frequency, age and monetary value into account. Using these values I receive accuracy of up to 80% but I'm sure this could be improved by incorporating more meaningful predictors into the model. Is it possible in this package? I couldn't find any information about it in the vignette. Any help is welcome, thanks!
Kasia

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, but I wanted to let you know that there's at least one other person with the same interest. I've been using a Python version of the library https://github.com/camDavidsonPilon/lifetimes/